# Shapeless HList parameter override

Tags: scala, shapeless, hlist

I have an abstract class with a method that receives an HList's as parameter (**A**).
However in the subclasses I'd like to restrict the exact types of this HList (**B**)

The code below doesn't work (it doesn't see `(Int :: String :: HNil)` as subclass of `HList`. But how can achieve a similar effect?

```scala
import shapeless.{::, HList, HNil}
import shapeless.syntax.std.tuple._

abstract class A{
  def test[H <: HList](h: H): String
}


class B extends A {
  override def test(h: (Int :: String :: HNil)): String = {
    val a = h(0)
    val b = h(1)
    s"$a -- $b"
  }
}


new B().test(25  :: "testje" ::  HNil)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even without HLists, this is not something you can do in Scala as-is.  Imagine trying to do something simpler

```
trait Foo
trait Bar extends Foo

abstract class A {
  def test[T <: Foo](t: T): String
}

class B extends A {
  override def test(b: Bar): String = //...
}
```

This doesn't work because `B.test` does not have the same signature as `A.test`.  One has a type parameter while the other does not.  Inheritance requires that a `B` should be able to act as an `A`, but that clearly cannot happen here.

Instead, you could move the type parameter to the class itself:

```
abstract class A[T <: Foo] {
  def test(t: T): String
}

class B extends A[Bar] {
  override def test(b: Bar): String = //...
}
```

This should also work fine when using HLists.